# Marklogic- RESTAPI-Invalid Content

Tags: marklogic

```
 rapi:status-code:['400'],
'rapi:status':['Bad Request'],
'rapi:message-code':['RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT'],
'rapi:message':['RESTAPI-INVALID CONTENT:(err:FOER0000)Invalid content: invalid cwapi extension].
```

I defined a module namespace `cwapi`.When I `import cwapi.xqy xquery file`, I get the above error. Do I have to change the output type? What do I do?

Comment: Where are you importing the module? Can you give a little more background about your problem and what you're trying to do?

Comment: @wst: I am using NodeJS. I created a resource service extension- cwapi and defined all the functions - get,post, put, delete, triple. I am trying to import the module to localhost:8080/resources/cwapi

Comment: Did you install the resource service extension successfully at /v1/config/resources/cwapi before trying to access it at /v1/resources/cwapi?  You might also want to look at the server log for more detailed error messages.

Comment: Which release of MarkLogic are you using?

Comment: @ehennym:  i didnt install resource service extension. How to check the server log error messages?

Comment: @mblakele: i am using marklogic 7.

Comment: There have been two releases of MarkLogic 7: 7.0-1 and 7.0-2.1. Which release are you using?

Comment: @mblakele: I am using 7.0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the resource service extension before you can use it. Please see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions